# Need help regarding single player for my snake and ladder game

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm new to java and making this game for my college project

It is basically user vs cpu game. 
so once the user has clicked for its turn(i.e the 1st method in the code) how do i make the system call the method on its own after the user's turn??

The code i have listed here in that i need to move the mouse out of startbutton to make the system play so its kind of an input..is there any other way out??

```
private void singlePlayerModeGame(final Stage primaryStage) {

    System.out.println("singlePlayerModeGame is called");
    foreground_startButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

            turnIndicator.setText("USER START");
            System.out.println("USER!");

            System.out.println("togglePlayer -- " + togglePlayer);

            if (togglePlayer == 0) {

                do {
                    togglePlayer = 1;
                    face = r.nextInt(7);

                    switch (face) {
                        case 1:
                            rollDice1(primaryStage);
                            face = 1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rollDice2(primaryStage);
                            face = 2;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rollDice3(primaryStage);
                            face = 3;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rollDice4(primaryStage);
                            face = 4;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            rollDice5(primaryStage);
                            face = 5;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            rollDice6(primaryStage);
                            face = 6;
                            break;
                    }
                } while (face == 6);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void singlePlayerSystemGame(final Stage primaryStage) {

    System.out.println("singlePlayerSystemGame is called");

    foreground_startButton.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

            if (togglePlayer == 1) {

                do {
                    togglePlayer = 0;
                    turnIndicator.setText("System START");
                    face = r.nextInt(7);
                    switch (face) {
                        case 1:
                            rollDice1(primaryStage);
                            face = 1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rollDice2(primaryStage);
                            face = 2;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            rollDice3(primaryStage);
                            face = 3;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rollDice4(primaryStage);
                            face = 4;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            rollDice5(primaryStage);
                            face = 5;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            rollDice6(primaryStage);
                            face = 6;
                            break;
                    }
                } while (face == 6);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: First, pick a framework.  Swing and JavaFX are different frameworks

Comment: doing it on javafx..don't go by the tags

Answer (score 0):

I would call both methods in seperate threads and do something like this:

```
while(!exit) //your end of game condition
{
    if(togglePlayer == 1){
        do{
            /*your logic*/
        }while()//move tooglePlayer = 0 out of this loop
        synchronized(lock){
            tooglePlayer = 0;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
    else{
        synchronized (lock){
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do this for both methods. Also lock and exit condition should be visible for both methods. Declare lock as:`Object lock = new Lock();` with modfiers as needed.